# Grouping multiple index and add grouping keys python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have data set in .csv like below, I want to use python to make group by and add one column as internal_id.

### input file

```
unq_id  name    city    country   supplier
053     ABC     CAL     UA        sup_01
054     DEF     NY      UA        sup_01
055     ABC     CAL     UA        sup_02
056     ABC     CAL     UA        sup_03
057     DEF     NY      UA        sup_02
```

### output file have to be new .csv file

```
 internal_id   unq_id     supplier
 001           053        sup_01    
 001           055        sup_02
 001           056        sup_03
 002           054        sup_01
 002           057        sup_02
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what you've tried so far and what problems you ran into you'd like to get help with.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in python. I did the "df.groupby('name')" and I get the output with grouping of name, but the actual I want to do is groupby with 3 column, which is 'name', 'city', 'county'. Then add internal_id for the same group like the **output file** that I mentioned. May you guide me with an example python code to let me try out? Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Pandas and [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# read file
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# define key columns
key_cols = ['name', 'city', 'country']

# convert to integer category codes
df['cat'] = df[key_cols].apply(tuple, axis=1).astype('category').cat.codes

# add one, convert to string, and format
df['cat'] = (df['cat'] + 1).apply(str).str.zfill(3)

# filter columns
res = df[['cat', 'unq_id', 'supplier']]

# output result to csv
res.to_csv('file_out.csv', index=False)

print(res)

   cat  unq_id supplier
0  001      53   sup_01
1  002      54   sup_01
2  001      55   sup_02
3  001      56   sup_03
4  002      57   sup_02
```